# how to read emails with special chars

Tags: bash, email, special-characters

I have tons of email in my inbox (mostly spam), I have a php script that reads email all of these emails and put them in different folders (I have a custom php email reader using the imap php functions).

My problem is this:

> Some emails have weird characeters in it, here is a sample:
>   *Search Engine Marketing will increase your companyâ<80><99>s online presence through comprehensive online marketing campaigns*

I can convert the `&acirc;` without any problems, but as you can see I have `<80><99>` chars, how can I go about converting them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to convert from one encoding to another.

Answer (score 1):

That's not `acirc<80><99>`, it's utf-8 for Unicode RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.